# Android: App icon disappearing After updating app to the latest version from Stub app?

Tags: java, android, mobile, google-play

Stub app: stub application is a tiny app that direct the user to download the full version on Google Play once the application is launched.

Only have this code in main activity:

```
final String appName = "com.example";
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id="+appName)));
```

stub apk will have the same package name, signed with the same certificate but have a lower version code. All while only pointing to the Google Play product page. Is that all that's needed.

After Updaing to latest version the shortcut icon is disappearing.
**Launcher activity is same as in the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

The icon disappears when the Activity with the launch intent changes. Giving the activity targeted by the launch intent the same name for both apps might solve the problem.